# Command to remotely restart another computer on same network, In Windows and Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, command-prompt

What command do I use to remotely restart another computer on our network, through command prompt with windows? And what is this same command in Linux terminal?

Comment: not an appropriate question.

Answer (score 1):

Google should sort u out.

Here's some possibilities assuming you wish to reboot a linux machine (either local or remote):

**Local**

(as root)

```
/sbin/shutdown -r now
```

or

```
$ sudo reboot
```

**Remote**

You will definitely need to get access to the remote machine before you can reboot it. So, the best bet is grabbing [ssh](http://www.openssh.com/) or [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) (for windows).

With ssh, you can reboot a remote linux machine like this:

```
$ ssh root@remote-server.com /sbin/reboot
```

or

```
$ ssh root@remote-server.com /sbin/shutdown -r now
```

Enjoy!

More ideas discussed [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-reboot-linux/)